# Where did I make a Javascript error in this short section of code?

Tags: javascript

I have made a short demo of a javascript problem.  When the Submit button is clicked, the alert pops up informing the user that a blank value is not allowed, which is good.  But then the page submits anyways, which is bad.

It seems this behavior is only happending on hidden fields.

(Its more clear if you enter any value into the name field. Click Submit. I know the page submits because the value in Name clears out.)

Can anyone see what is wrong here?

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="" method="post" name="form" onsubmit='return validate()'>

Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name">

<br><br>Signature: Hidden <input type="hidden" name="poa_esign_signature" id="poa_esign_signature">

<br><br><button type="submit">Sign</button>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function validate() {
  var element=document.getElementById('poa_esign_signature');
  if (element.value=='') {
    alert('Signature may not be blank.');
    element.focus();
    return false;
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: seems to work for me. Compare http://jsfiddle.net/dUAsr/ and http://jsfiddle.net/dUAsr/1

Comment: I went to jsfiddle.net/dUAsr and jsfiddle.net/dUAsr/1 and I dont see it working there.  The way I know is that I enter any value into the name field.  Click Submit, the page submits eben though it should not.  I know the pages is submitting because the value in Name clears out.

Comment: I just tested it in chrome.  dUAsr doesn't clear out the value, but dUAsr/1 does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your console.  I bet the `element.focus()` is failing, because its a hidden input.  Seems odd to focus on a hidden element.

Comment: I forgot about that line.  I did a lot of testing, and your answer was the only one that fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an `<input type="submit">` rather than a `<button type="submit">`. I'm not sure if it'll make a difference, but it might be it.

Comment: That did not fix it.  Thats how I make buttons in the whole app, and it always works on all other pages.  The problem is the input element vs the other element.

Comment: not sure if its a typo, but i noticed you didn't close your input tags

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function()
{
    var _form = document.getElementById("_form");
    _form.addEventListener("submit", validate, false);
}

function validate(ev) 
{
  var element=document.getElementById('poa_esign_signature');
  if (element.value=='') 
  {
    alert('Signature may not be blank.');
    element.focus();
    ev.preventDefault();
  }
}

</script>

<form action="www.google.it" method="post" name="form" id="_form">

Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name">

<br><br>Signature: Hidden <input type="hidden" name="poa_esign_signature" id="poa_esign_signature">

<br><br><button type="submit">Sign</button>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Bye

Answer (score -1):

```
onsubmit='return validate()'
```

should be

```
onsubmit='validate()'
```

Comment: You sure?  I'm pretty sure `return validate()` is required in order to work. I prefer the trailing `;`, but that probably isn't a problem.

Comment: No... but I did miss that you need an else to return true in the validate function... then it should work.